# chartJS - How to customize x-axis scale / ticks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I've recently been working on a project involving Chart.JS. I'm looking to scale the x-axis so that 50% width goes from values 0-100 while the other 50% width of the chart goes from 100 - 1000.

I'm using a horizontal stacked bar chart with 3 datasets. This can be seen [here](https://i.gyazo.com/e6aa00dc4938221d131478e3157f3677.png)

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this [here](https://i.gyazo.com/2a7ad69088e57e3b3d634f1b3127dbfa.png), except the 500 would be 100 and the 1000 would remain 1000. i.e. the graph wouldn't have a linear scale.

I'm attempting to do this as anything above around 150 is pretty much an outlier and I'm not worried about it going over 1000.

[Here](https://i.gyazo.com/f1625d5bca38b4cf9246facab585edaa.png) is my current config for the chart (I'm using `react-chartjs` and react)

I've react the documentation on chart.js and viewed some GitHub issue posts but can't find to find anyone with a similar problem. Maybe I'm misunderstanding one of the properties of the ticks object.

Anyway, thanks to everyone and anyone that replies! Will edit once I find a solution.

Chart Config Code Block

```
options= {{
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
        display: true,
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                maxTicksLimit: 3
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
        }]
    }
}}
```